# Format datestamp in python

Tags: python, datetime, date, format, timestamp

Using `import datetime` in python, is it possible to take a formatted time/date string such as:

```
2012-06-21 20:36:11
```

And convert it into an object that I can then use to produce a newly formatted string such as:

```
21st June 2012 20:36
```

Comment: Checkout strftime http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import time

s = '2012-06-21 20:36:11'

t = time.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print time.strftime('%d %B %Y %H:%M', t)
```

returns

```
21 June 2012 20:36
```

---

If you really want the 'st',

```
def nth(n):
    return str(n) + nth.ext[int(n)%10]
nth.ext = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'] + ['th']*6

print nth(t.tm_mday) + time.strftime(' %B %Y %H:%M', t)
```

gets you

```
21st June 2012 20:36
```

Comment: +1 for a nice solution.  I also like the trick of tucking a private variable for a function inside the function object, as you did with `nth.ext`; I do that too.

Answer (score 1):

You want `datetime.strptime`, it parses text into datetimes:

```
>>> d = "2012-06-21 20:36:11"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 21, 20, 36, 11)
```

Formatting the date in the way you want is almost doable:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(t, "%d %B %Y %H:%m")
'21 June 2012 20:06'
```